# Consulta por error en Visual Studio

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2017, bootstrap-3

Estoy trabajando con Visual Studio 2017 y estoy realizando una página web con ASP y Visual Basic.

Le cargué la versión de Bootstrap 3.4.1, el CSS y jQuery. Si pruebo mi App cargándola desde el mismo Visual me corre bien, pero cuando quiero publicarla me tira como 180 errores de:

> eqeqeq     (ESLint) Expected '===' and instead saw '=='    bootstrap.js

¿Esto es un error del archivo Bootstrap o algo del Visual? ¿Cómo puedo arreglar este error?

Comment: El bootsrap como lo estas referenciando?

Comment: como cualquier link, para el js <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>. Si no he hecho nada raro

Answer (score 0):

Debes configurar tu ESLint para que ignore los archivos de librerias externas y/o la carpeta node_modules o bien usar una version actualizada de Bootstrap que no contenga estos errores.

Comment: mm ok. voy a ver en qué parte del visual se hace lo que me dices y comento, gracias.